# Why did the French constitution of 1791 not extend its effect to the colonies?

Tags: french-revolution, constitution

[The French Constitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Constitution_of_1791) of 1791, which was accepted during the Revolution and followed the Declaration of the Rights of Man and of the Citizen (1789), contained such a provision that stated that

> The French colonies and possessions in Asia, Africa, and America,
> although constituting part of the French dominion, are not included in
> the present Constitution.

What was this provision's purpose? Did it mean that French colonists was not eligible to exercise the whole set of guaranteed rights and freedoms (perhaps they was not allowed to elect their representatives in the National Assembly) or it was primarily concerned with non-French people rights diminishing? (As we know, France had not yet abolished colonial slavery by that moment.)